# Sync OutLook with salesforce

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

I have a requirement where i want to create an event outlook when an event is created in **salesforce**.

This can be done manually but by clicking the button and uploading the file into outlook.

I want it to done automatically when an event is created in salesforce an event has to get created  in outlook

Comment: This is exactly what the Salesforce for Outlook application does? When an event is created in Salesforce, Salesforce for Outlook syncs and adds it to that user's calendar.

Comment: Use AppExchange. It has everything you want. Its Google Play for your Salesforce platform.

Answer (score 4):

> I want it to done automatically when an event is created in salesforce an event has to get created in outlook

This is exactly what the Salesforce for Outlook does. It's an addon for Outlook provided by Salesforce.

You'd need to define exactly how you'd want this to work, and who has access to it by going to:

> Setup > Desktop Administration > Outlook Configurations

Here you'd need to create and make active a configuration.

You can download the application itself by going to My Settings.

Once downloaded, you'd need to sign into Salesforce via the app and follow the installation process from there (e.g. what you want to sync, should it sync private items etc...)

Comment: Can I have the steps I want to create a calendar event on outlook using salesforce or through an email template

Comment: @user6833 I've literally told you the steps? You'll want to go into Outlook Configurations and set one up for your Org. That Configuration entirely depends on what you want. There's a multi select picklist that assigns who has access to the Configuration. Then you'll just need to download and install the add on, then sign in. Any events created will then sync.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link to some setup videos and a quick start guide for Salesforce for Outlook. In this scenario if you want Salesforce to control when events are created, you will want to setup a sync that flows in one direction from Salesforce to Outlook. You wouldn't want to sync in both directions. Make sure that the users have their "Acceptable Email Address" set to their true email address so that the information gets where it's supposed to go. Here is the link https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewQuickStarts?id=000113374